# Key not found in the data frame although it already exists

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to render a box-plot using the ggplot. When I run the following:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=disp, y=cyl)) + geom_boxplot()
```

I get an error saying: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'disp' not found`, although `mtcars$disp` prints the result.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: You used `mpg` not `mtcars` as the data argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mpg` is a data-set (a `tibble`) inside the `ggplot2` package.
It has a column called `displ` rather than `disp`.

Also otherwise, the `mpg` tibble is not identical to the `mtcars` data.frame.